# Откат транзакции в MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Допустим, я запускаю некоторый код в транзакции.
Затем, по каким-то соображениям я прерываю запрос нажатием на соответствующую кнопку.

Транзакция должна была сама автоматически откатится?

Просто, обнаружил лишь спустя какое-то время, что транзакция не откатилась. И обнаружил это только, когда пытался закрыть вкладку с запросом и мне написалось про неподтвержденные транзакции.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, не должна. Транзакция откатывается по явному `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` или закрывается по явному `COMMIT TRANSACTION`. Если ни то ни другое не было вызвано транзакция будет продолжать висеть открытой. Посмотреть висячие транзакции можно командой `DBCC OPENTRAN`.

Как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694894/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-ms-sql#comment1029007_694899) верно подметили транзакция откатится при закрытии соединения. Здесь есть правда нюанс связанный с пулингом соединений. Так что закрытие на стороне клиента не всегда означает моментальный откат, т.к. соединение (вместе с незакрытой транзакцией) вернется в пул и будет там неопределённое время висеть.

Comment: И даже нету никакого времени жизни таких висячих транзакций, что бы автоматом откат произошел?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, будут висеть вечно пока не будет подтверждения или отката.

Comment: Или пока связь не оборвется

Comment: @Kladivo это верное замечание.